# json to xml conversion in mulesoft

Tags: json, mule, esb

I am giving input as JSON file using post method.

```
{
    "student":[
    {
        "id":"101",
            "name":"sindhu",
            "branch":"cse"
    },
    {
        "id":"102",
        "name":"anusha",
        "branch":"ece"
    },
    {
        "id":"103",
        "name":"teja",
        "branch":"cse"
    },
    {
        "id":"104",
        "name":"anju",
        "branch":"ece"
    }
    ]
   }
```

I want output in XML using groupBy operator, for example groupBy "branch".

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<flow name="stackoverflowFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
            path="/jsonToXml" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload>
            <![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
"student": payload.student groupBy $.branch
}]]>
        </dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <json:json-to-xml-transformer doc:name="JSON to XML" />
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Final Output:

```
<student>
   <cse>
      <id>101</id>
      <name>sindhu</name>
      <branch>cse</branch>
   </cse>
   <cse>
      <id>103</id>
      <name>teja</name>
      <branch>cse</branch>
   </cse>
   <ece>
      <id>102</id>
      <name>anusha</name>
      <branch>ece</branch>
   </ece>
   <ece>
      <id>104</id>
      <name>anju</name>
      <branch>ece</branch>
   </ece>
</student>
```